# Objective C - Passing/retrieving selected image from UIImageView to second VC with tableview so cell can display that image

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

i already passed input text with prepareForSegue, text into mutablearray, then passing that array with prepareforeSegue to second VC with tableview so table cell now displays name. But what with selected/picked image in uIImageView in first vc so table cell in second VC can display image in a row next to name? i manage to do it with image from imagexxassets i followed the same logic like passing text but keep failing.

**VIewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "TableViewController.h"
    #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputName;

    @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
    //@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;

    - (IBAction)AddData:(id)sender;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *selectPhoto;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *takePhotoFromCamera;
    @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()


    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        _items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        //_images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [self.takePhotoFromCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(_takePhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.selectPhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(_selectPhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    - (IBAction)AddData:(id)sender
    {
        //[_images addObject:self.imageView.image];
        //[_images insertObject:self.imageView.image atIndex:0];
        if ([self.inputName.text length]> 0)
        {
            [_items addObject:self.inputName.text];
            //[_images addObject:self.imageView.image];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tableSegue" sender:self];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView =  [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:@"You must enter some data"
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }

    }

    - (void)addItemViewController:(TableViewController *)controller didFinishSelectingItem:(NSMutableArray *)item selectedTag:(int)tag{
        NSLog(@"DATA=%@", item);

    }

    - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tableSegue"])
        {

            TableViewController *controller = (TableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            controller.items = _items;
            //TableViewController *controller1 = (TableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            //controller1.images = _images;
            NSLog(@"%@",self.inputName.text);
            self.inputName.text = NULL;
        }
    }


    #pragma mark code for images
    -(void)_takePhoto
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    -(void)_selectPhoto
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
        {
            UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            self.imageView.image = image;
        }
    }

    -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:
    (UIImagePickerController *)picker
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @end
```

**TableViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    //using delegate
    @protocol TableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)addItemViewController:(id)controller didFinishSelectingItem:(NSMutableArray *)item selectedTag:(int)tag;

    @end
                                    //extra attention here
    @interface TableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

    // id of delegate
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id <TableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

    @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
    //@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    @end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
    #import "TableViewController.h"

    @interface TableViewController ()


    @end

    @implementation TableViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // code for reversing objects in array so tableview can put new rows on top
        //_items = [[[_items reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];

        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;

        // setting invisible footer to display only rows which contains data and to remove border lines in tableview
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 10.0f)];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BasicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //NSString *lijevaSlika = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice%i", sum];
        //[questionTexts objectAtIndex:0]
       //NSString *selectedImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:_images];

        myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        myCell.textLabel.text = _items[indexPath.row]; //name of objects in array are displayed in cells
        myCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor]; //changing color of text in cell

        //changing background of cell
        /*myCell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]];
         myCell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"front.png"]];
         */


        return myCell;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        return [self.items count]; //objects in arrays - rows in table

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [_items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //swipe to left do delete row
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    /*- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //selected row returns to previous viewcontroller
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    */



    /*
    #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to store selected images in array then you have to pass that array in same way you are passing `_items` array.Then In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of `TableViewController` add this line and check you are getting anything in `_images` array

```
myCell.imageView.image =  [_images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: omg, thank you alot, i was retriving with myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_images"]; and got errors, i used your code and now it works, i can't thank you enough :)

Comment: you see code for uialertview in VC.m, it says if textfield is empty show uialert view, how to do the same if image is not chosen. like if UIImageView is nill do uialertview, will try

Comment: thank you, i resolved it with if ([self.inputName.text length]> 0 && imageView.image != nil)